# MGWT [ERROR] Trying to sink unknown event type webkitAnimationEnd

Tags: java, gwt, mgwt

I'm currently developing a mgwt  application using some techniques in showcase. Anyway, on a line when calling MGWTPlaceHistoryHandler.handleCurrentHistory method in entry point (initialization of first view) i got this error:

**com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (String)
@com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.DOMImplStandard::sinkBitlessEventImpl(Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Element;Ljava/lang/String;)([JavaScript object(20), string: 'webkitAnimationEnd']): Trying to sink unknown event type webkitAnimationEnd**

I can't figure out, what causes this type of error. The exception message is kinda vague - I'm not using any custom native methods affecting target DOM and JS code.

Any ideas ? I'm really clueless about this :(

PS: a part of code where this problem occurs:

```
AppPlaceHistoryMapper historyMapper= GWT.create(AppPlaceHistoryMapper.class);
AppHistoryObserver historyObserver= new  AppHistoryObserver();
MGWTPlaceHistoryHandler historyHandler= new  MGWTPlaceHistoryHandler(historyMapper,historyObserver);
historyHandler.register(clientFactory.getPlaceController(),clientFactory.getEventBus(),new  MyDefaultPlace());
historyHandler.handleCurrentHistory(); //Exception thrown here
```

Any help or tips appreciated, I got stuck on this problem for a hours. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] - never EVER, EVER EVER use latest MGWT on older versions of GWT [2.5.1] ;)

Comment: Thank you so much - have been trying for many hours trying to figure this out and bumping from 2.5.1 to 2.6.1 seems to have solved it!